# MySQL Query Cost

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, benchmarking

Can someone tell me the theoretical difference in the expensive of the following queries?

- `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category IN(1)`
- `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category IN(1,2)`
- `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category IN(1,2,3)`

... etc ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, if you had an index on category AND the table was sizable enough AND the index is selective, then

```
Cost for 1st as baseline = N
Cost of 2nd = 2 x N
Cost of 3rd = 3 x N
```

If there is no index or the index is not selective enough (e.g. category=1 covers 10% of the table) then it will perform a table scan.  If the table is small, it will not even bother to use the index.  In which case

```
Cost of 1st as baseline = N + X
Cost of 2nd = N + 2X
Cost of 3rd = N + 3X
```

The reason is that a full table scan is cost N. During the scan, it will use X time pick out the entire row (`select *`) so there is a little bit more involved in processing more categories, but not so significant as to affect the baseline time required to scan the table.

Comment: Makes sense that it would be linear.  I guess I was making it too complicated!